# Does Jubula support GEF/GMF elements?

Tags: jubula

I am trying to create functional test cases for a gmf application Using "Jubula Version: 1.2.0 "

About the AUT:
The application (eclipse based) has graphical elements in a "Palette". From this palette I want to select elements and drop them on the "Editor" to create a diagram.

Problems I am facing:

1. There is no option in Jubula to expand a Palette.
2. From what I searched, I am not able to find any information about how Jubula works with gmf elements.

Answer (score 0):

Information on how to test GEF editors in general using Jubula can be found in the official Eclipse online help system:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help/html/manual/node329.html?cp=24_3_2

The Eclipse Jubula forum might also be a good place to check / ask any Jubula-specific questions:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=208

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse help docs says 'it is highly recommended that application developers enhance this support by implementing an accessibility plug-in for their application.'

So if you made some custom elements using GEF, you'd better make some plug-ins for Jubula to work with your application.

Refer to this : 
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help%2Fhtml%2Fmanual%2Fnode332.html